# Determine the values of $p$ for which the integral of $\sup_n f_n(x)$ converges to $0$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

Consider $f_n(x)=n^px^n(1-x)$ on $[0,1]$. Then $\lim_{n\to \infty}f_n(x)=0$ for $x\in [0,1]$. I already know that if and only if $p<2$, 
 we have$\int_{[0,1]} f_n(x)\mathrm{d}x\to 0$. I am asked for which values of $p$,  $\sup_nf_n(x)$ is integrable on $[0,1]$.

I tried to take derivative of $f_n(x)=n^px^n(1-x)$ with respect to $n$, and look for the expression of $\sup_nf_n(x)$. But it seems this does not help me much doing this way. I already see that, when $p\leq 1$, $\sup_nf_n(x)$ is integrable. But I still have difficulty when considering $p>1$. Any hint for this? Thank you for your help!

Comment: We can easily show that if $p>2$ then for sure $\sup_n f_n(x)$ is not integrable. Observe that
$$0\leq  f_n(x) \leq \sup_{n} f_n(x) \qquad \Longrightarrow \qquad \int_0^1 |f_n(x)|\;dx \leq \int_0^1 \sup_{n} f_n(x)\;dx$$
Which implies that
$$ \frac{n^p}{(n+1)(n+2)} = \int_0^1 |f_n(x)|\;dx \leq \int_0^1 \sup_{n} f_n(x)\;dx$$
for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$. You can see that if $p>2$ then the left hand side tends to infinity as $n\longrightarrow \infty$, thus $\sup_n f_n(x)$ cannot be integrable if $p>2$.

Comment: Oh thank you. But the difficulty is the part $1<p\leq2$. I don't know how to get good estimation here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Differentiation with respect to $n$ might work. Assuming $n$ to be a continuous variable we get
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial n}n^px^n=pn^{p-1}x^n+n^px^n\ln x=0\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad p+n\ln x=0\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad n=\frac{p}{\ln(1/x)}=\log_{1/x}e^p.
$$
It is easy to see that it is maximum. Hence,
$$
x^n=\frac{1}{(1/x)^n}=\frac{1}{e^p}=e^{-p}
$$
and
$$
\sup_n f_n=p^pe^{-p}\frac{1-x}{\ln^p(1/x)}.
$$
The integral has singularity at $x=1$. Change the variable to e.g. $1/x=1+t$ to see the asymtotics of this singularity to be
$$
\frac{t}{\ln^p(1+t)}\sim \frac{t}{t^p}=\frac{1}{t^{p-1}} 
$$
as $t\to 0$. The RHS function is integrable at $(0,\epsilon)$ iff $p<2$.